# Setting context state with vs without constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-context

When I try to initialize my state without a constructor I get issues with the functions not binding to the state. Doing the following doesn't work despite the fact that tutorials like [this](https://dev.to/sunnysingh/sharing-state-using-reacts-context-api-3623) initialize the state directly without the constructor.

This doesn't pass the functions to the consumer:

```
class NewTownFormContextProvider extends Component {
        state = {
            towns:[],
            name: '',
            parish: '',
            categories:[],
            catList:[],
            resetForm: this.resetForm,
            updateTown: this.updateTown,
            updateParish: this.updateParish,
            setCategory: this.setCategory,
            submit: this.submit

        }


    resetForm = ()=>{
        this.setState({
            name:'',
            parish:'',
            categories:[]
        })
    }

    updateTown = (e) =>{
        this.setState({town: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.town);
    }
    updateParish = (e) =>{
        this.setState({parish: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.parish);
    }

    setCategory = (e) =>{
        this.setState({category: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.category);
    }

    submit = async (e) => {
        e.  preventDefault();
        this.setState([...this.state.towns, {name: this.state.town, parish: this.state.parish}])
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        let data = await fetch(`${d}/town/get-categories`);
        let catList = await data.json();
        this.setState({ catList });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <NewTownFormContext.Provider value={{...this.state  }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </NewTownFormContext.Provider>  
        );
    };
}
```

But this does:

```
class NewTownFormContextProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            towns:[],
            name: '',
            parish: '',
            categories:[],
            catList:[],
            resetForm: this.resetForm,
            updateTown: this.updateTown,
            updateParish: this.updateParish,
            setCategory: this.setCategory,
            submit: this.submit

        }
    }


    resetForm = ()=>{
        this.setState({
            name:'',
            parish:'',
            categories:[]
        })
    }

    updateTown = (e) =>{
        this.setState({town: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.town);
    }
    updateParish = (e) =>{
        this.setState({parish: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.parish);
    }

    setCategory = (e) =>{
        this.setState({category: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.category);
    }

    submit = async (e) => {
        e.  preventDefault();
        this.setState([...this.state.towns, {name: this.state.town, parish: this.state.parish}])
 }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        let data = await fetch(`${d}/town/get-categories`);
        let catList = await data.json();
        this.setState({ catList });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <NewTownFormContext.Provider value={{...this.state  }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </NewTownFormContext.Provider>  
        );
    };
}
```

I'm not sure why the tutorials specify the first method.

Comment: Can you show your webpack config?

Comment: I created this app with create-react-app so its kinda long.

Comment: In that case it should support class properties, I think @HMR answer will solve your issue

Comment: After giving the answer I realised that there is no need to add class methods to the state, not sure why you think you needed to do this.

Comment: If you're saying that because these mostly just set data I'm using some very specific functions that sets the state in a way where it would be a good solution. Like taking contents from one state and using it to update other state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the functions before the state:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  resetForm = () => {
    console.log('reset form');
  };
  state = {
    resetForm: this.resetForm,
  };

  render() {
    this.state.resetForm();
    return 'hi';
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

This looks like an x y problem, not sure why you need to add class methods to state.